# pymssql throws ImportError: No module named _mssql when build app with py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe, pymssql

I have python application that shoud be launched as windows executable. I'm using py2exe and pymssql 1.9.908.

I used next build script to generate application:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import MySQLdb
import fnmatch
import os
import pymssql
import shutil
import py2exe
import glob

##############

name = 'BGAgent'
old_version = '0.1'
ver = '0.1'

distDir = 'Dist' + name + ver
shutil.rmtree(distDir, True)
shutil.rmtree('Dist' + name + old_version, True)

os.mkdir(distDir)

##############

class Target(object):
    """ A simple class that holds information on our executable file. """
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        """ Default class constructor. Update as you need. """
        self.__dict__.update(kw)

# MySQLdb
#dst = os.path.join(distDir, "MySQLdb")
#copy_tree(MySQLdb.__path__[0], dst )
# pymssql
site_packages_dir = os.path.dirname(pymssql.__file__)
pymssql_files = []#'pymssql.py', 'pymssql.pyc', 'pymssql.pyo', '_mssql.pyd']
for eggInfo in glob.glob(os.path.join(site_packages_dir, '*mssql*')) :
    pymssql_files.append(os.path.basename(eggInfo))

for fname in pymssql_files :
    src = os.path.join(site_packages_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(distDir, fname)
    if(os.path.isfile(src)) :
        shutil.copy(src, dst)
    else :
        shutil.copytree(src, dst)

includes = ['MySQLdb', 'pymssql', 'OpenSSL']
excludes = ['run_w.exe'] #['_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'curses', 'email', 'pywin.debugger', 'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs', 'tcl', 'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter']

packages = ['MySQLdb', 'pymssql', 'OpenSSL']

dll_excludes = []#['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll', 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 'tcl84.dll', 'tk84.dll']

data_files = ['server.pem', 
              'config.ini', 
              'run.bat',
              #os.path.join(os.path.split(pymssql.__file__)[0], 'ntwdblib.dll'),
              ]
icon_resources = []
bitmap_resources = []
other_resources = []


MyApp_Target = Target(
    # what to build
    script = "run.py",
    icon_resources = icon_resources,
    bitmap_resources = bitmap_resources,
    other_resources = other_resources,
    dest_base = name,    
    version = ver,
    company_name = "",
    copyright = "",
    name = name,
    )


setup(
    data_files = data_files,
    options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 0, 
                          "optimize": 1,
                          "includes": includes,
                          "excludes": excludes,
                          "packages": packages,
                          "dll_excludes": dll_excludes,
                          "bundle_files": 3,
                          "dist_dir": distDir,
                          "xref": False,
                          "skip_archive": False,
                          "ascii": False,
                          "custom_boot_script": '',
                         }
              },
    zipfile = r'library.zip',
    console = [],
    windows = [MyApp_Target],
    service = [],
    com_server = [],
    ctypes_com_server = []
    )
```

Build works, but I have error when I tried to launch application:

```
  File "pymssql.pyo", line 12, in <module>
  File "pymssql.pyo", line 10, in __load
  File "_mssql.pxd", line 10, in init pymssql (pymssql.c:7370)
ImportError: No module named _mssql
```

_mssql.pyd and pymssql.pyd files are in executable directory.

OS version Windows 7 Enterprice SP 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the program you are trying to import (eg. in the A.py for  A.exe ), specify import statement for _mssql as well. You might also need to import a couple of other modules (decimal & uuid )to get the exe working

Comment: It was bug in pymssql. If I do import of _mssql before socket module implicitly all works fine. I found how to fix this but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the statement `import _mssql` in your file. Next, run your program. When you get the same thing, just import that module in your code. This method works well for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
from distutils.core import setup

import py2exe, os, pymssql
import decimal

data_files = []
data_files.append(os.path.join(os.path.split(pymssql.__file__)[0], 'ntwdblib.dll'))
py2exe_options = {"py2exe":{"includes": ['decimal'],
                "dll_excludes":["mswsock.dll",
                "powrprof.dll",
                "user32.dll",
                "shell32.dll",
                "wsock32.dll",
                "advapi32.dll",
                "kernel32.dll",
                "ntwdblib.dll",
                "ws2_32.dll",
                "oleaut32.dll",
                "ole32.dll",
                            ],
}}

setup(console=["jobs_pcc_main.py"], options= py2exe_options, data_files=data_files)
```

Comment: hi, i post my setup.py, i have met the same issue, please refer to this setup.py, i think your code will be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Why you include ntwdblib.dll as data file and exclude as DLL? What is the trick? My problem was with socket module. It looks like pymssql monkey-patching it and I imported it before the pymssql.

Answer (score 0):

To whom might help
I got lots of issues trying to user pymssql with Pyinstaller and
I finally got it right so posting here might help someone
after you install pymssql using pip install pymssql

use this parameters in pyinstaller to get it included

```
--onefile --paths=.\venv\ --hidden-import='pymssql' --hidden-import='uuid' --collect-all='pymssql' --collect-all='uuid'
```