# How to get rid of the error "_ms sql" not found

Tags: pyinstaller

There is a script with import pymssql.

I'm trying to compile this file with this command

As a result, I get an error:

45873 WARNING: Hidden import "_mssql" not found!

Maybe someone has encountered a similar one? Tell me what can be done?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixIMm.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937505/pymssql-throws-importerror-no-module-named-mssql-when-build-app-with-py2exe/69076700?noredirect=1#comment122085434_69076700

I tried to run the hints from here, but got an error

Comment: The image seems to relate a invalid string syntax rather than the Warning of the hidden import.

Comment: Yes, it was necessary to remove the quotation marks
Still swears and does not find
https://itfy.org/attachments/1630999538354-png.1341/

Comment: Did you use the latest version of PyInstaller?

Comment: Yes, I checked through the command
pyinstaller               4.5.1
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2021.3

Comment: It turned out to build an exe file through the cx_Freeze library

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `pymssql > 2.1.5`, you can add these arguments:

```
--hidden-import decimal --hidden-import pymssql._mssql --hidden-import uuid
```

when running PyInstaller.

I have [updated the hook](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller-hooks-contrib/pull/315) for this.